# A graph which does not contain any cycle of length four

Tags: graph-theory

Consider the graph whose vertices are the 0/1-sequence of length $2n+1$ with $n$ or $n+1$ ones, and two sequences joined by and edge if they differ in exactly one coordinate. This is subgraph of $Q_{2n+1}$. Show that this graph does not contain any C4

Answer (score 4):

Such a cycle would go $v_1$-$w_1$-$v_2$-$w_2$-$v_1$
where the $v_i$ have $n$ $1$s and the $w_i$ $n+1$ $1$s.
Let $A_i$ be the set of the coordinate positions of $v_i$ and
let $B_i$ be the set of the coordinate positions of $w_i$.
Then $|A_i|=n$, $|B_i|=n+1$ and $A_i\subset B_j$ for all $i$
and $j$. As $A_1\ne A_2$ this implies that $B_1=A_1\cup A_2$;
it also implies $B_2=A_1\cup A_2$, oops!

Comment: one final edit ? ... al = all ... nice answer (+1)